# How to use $xpath with strip_tags

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

Could someone help me, how to  get the latest P(look below plz) tag from this div via $xpath? 
I coulndt, because, the other tags in class='mydiv' returns error as like:

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag article invalid in Entity, line: 2 in /tmp/execpad-35d38cb6bc34/source-35d38cb6bc34 on line xx

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 2 in /tmp/execpad-35d38cb6bc34/source-35d38cb6bc34 on line xx

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag time invalid in Entity, line: 2 in /tmp/execpad-35d38cb6bc34/source-35d38cb6bc34 on line xx

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 2 in /tmp/execpad-35d38cb6bc34/source-35d38cb6bc34 on line xx

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 2 in /tmp/execpad-35d38cb6bc34/source-35d38cb6bc34 on line xx

```
<div class="mydiv" role="main" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
<!-- google_ad_section_end --><!-- google_ad_section_start -->
<article id="768" class="768" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<header><h1 itemprop="name" class="entry-title">title here</h1>
<div class="meta-info">
<time itemprop="dateCreated" class="entry-date updated" datetime="2010-08-12T14:07:11+00:00">Aug 14, 2010</time>
<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserComments:9"/><div class="entry-comments-views">
</div></header>
<p>xxxx & xxxx</p>
<p>**i need here** </p>
</div>
```

i use this method to get second p tag

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$index = 2;
$class = 'mydiv';
$tai = $xpath->query(
    sprintf('//div[@class="%s"]/p', $class)
);
```

i need to strip invalid tags from html($doc)..

Comment: they're just warnings, not errors.

Comment: but... i cant get the second p tag, with these codes?

Comment: Well, I see an unclosed `<article>` & `<header>` & `<div class="meta-info">` (or whatever, it's atrociously invalid at any rate), with recovery added, that would make those `p`'s probably end up inside them. You can inspect `$doc->saveHTML();` to see how it recovers, you could work around it by using `'//div[@class="%s"]//p'`.